# White space margin (not images)

Tags: css, margin

I would like to know why upon selecting, there is a white space on the left of L, D, W (you can see on certain columns). Take note that they are not images, but styled with a background, so display:inline doesn't come into play, does it?

Thanks.

Image here: http://i.imm.io/1mRPp.jpeg

```
<tr class="pos1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="posindicator"><img alt="" src="http://www.premierleague.com/etc/designs/premierleague/images/shim.gif" /></td>
    <td>(3)</td>
    <td class="club"><a href="http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/clubs/profile.overview.html/newcastle">Newcastle Utd (S)</a></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><span class="form-win">W</span> <span class="form-win">W</span> <span class="form-nil">-</span></td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><span class="form-lose">L</span> <span class="form-win">W</span> <span class="form-win">W</span></td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><span class="form-win">W</span> <span class="form-win">W</span> <span class="form-win">W</span></td>
    <td>9</td>
</tr>
```

They are the same, just with different background colors.

```
.form-draw {
   background: #999;
   color: #fff;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 0;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 1.5em;
   height: 1.5em;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: There's pretty much no way anyone will answer this without code.

Comment: I have added the code as per above!

Comment: It's a starnge bug. Since it just affects a few boxes, I wouldn't thing `display:inline;` has anything to do with it. I do think that Jonathan Newmuis meant the CSS as well, since it probably is the CSS that is the issue.

Comment: @Psyberion Yeah, CSS is also included above. Not sure why tho.

Comment: @D.WONG We need the CSS because, as you so aptly put it in your tags, this (probably) is an issue with the CSS. To find the CSS bug we need to be able to analyze said code. Anyway, it's great that you've added it!

Comment: @D.WONG : the css you have provided is not for the html that you have posted...either post relevant code, or help yourself in finding the reasons by yourself! :)

Comment: What white space where?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela In the boxes to the left in the table, the ones containing "W", "L", "D" or "-".
As for the problem, I agree with Mayank. It would be great if you could post HTML for the whole table and all the CSS used to style that table. I am currently unable to replicate your bug, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Psyberion Hi, here is the fiddle (included all HTML & CSS codes). http://jsfiddle.net/VsYys/

Comment: Well, I don't see any bugs in the fiddle. I'd guess it's a compability bug with your browser. But do take a look at Carlo Cannas solution, it seems like it could work.

Comment: Hi @Psyberion Yup I guess it's a Chrome issue. Anyway, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's the whitespace character (`U+0020`) you left between the `span` elements, removing it the span boxes will be one next to the other.